# CodeContracts: Possibly calling a method on a null reference 'this.Master'

Tags: asp.net, code-contracts

If I have a basic master page and content page and I want to use some property or method of the master page from the content page, such as:

```
string something = this.Master.MasterPageFile;
```

Code Contracts static analysis will complain with:

```
warning : CodeContracts: Possibly calling a method on a null reference 'this.Master'
```

How can I get Code Contracts to stop complaining whenever I want to access the master page?

R.

[Edit]

Take a look at this?

```
public partial class Manage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Master.ShowFeedback("Test.", true);
    }

   [ContractInvariantMethod]
   private void ObjectInvariants()
   {
       Contract.Invariant(this.Master != null);
   }
}
```

I don't want to have to do the following every time I want to call Showfeedback():

```
Contract.Assume(this.Master != null)
this.Master.ShowFeedback("Test.", true);
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: You could ensure that `this.Master` won't be null?

Answer (score 0):

You can add it as an invariant to your class:

```
[ContractInvariantMethod]
private void Invariants()
{
    Contract.Invariant(Master != null);
}
```

Comment: I already tried that but Code Contracts came back with warning : CodeContracts: invariant unproven: this.Master != null

Comment: At the end of which method? The constructor?

Comment: I edited my code to show an example. Strange thing is, sometimes that call will not cause a warning. But say I access a method before making the call, then the warning will definitely fire. Confused.

Comment: That's rather weird behaviour. Perhaps you should ask about it on the Code Contracts forum :)